# How delete the border, which appears around a tag, when we click on it?

Tags: css

When we click on `a` tag, the  border is appear around it.
In Mozilla that border has the color of `a` tag, so when i set the color of a tag same as the background color of content, the border disappears, but in IE that border always white, so i don't know how delete it.

Any ideas?

Thanks much

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove outline.

```
a {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Don’t.**

This makes your site inaccessible to keyboard users. That may not sound like a big deal, but many people with relatively minor disabilities are unable to use a mouse.

At the very least, replace it with something else to indicate focus.

Comment: This is admittedly an edge case, but the border around an anchor is a visual irritant when used with jQuery tabs. In this instance the designer will likely want to hide the border.

Answer (score 2):

```
:link:focus, :visited:focus { 
-moz-outline: none; 
}
```

From:  http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/8697.htm

Comment: -1. There’s no sensible reason to use `-moz-outline`. This only works in Mozilla browsers and will probably stop working in future. Just use `outline`.

Comment: As long as we're being truthful, there is no sensible reason to do it at all.  But, I see you've pointed that out in your post as well.